# using json objects in URLSearchParams

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

Is it possible to somehow append json objects onto a URLSearchParams object?

So instead of:

```
urlSearchParams.append('search', 'person');
```

it's:

```
urlSearchParams.append({search: "person"});
```

**My answer courtesy of Darshak Gajjar's answer**

Can use json objects via this way:

```
let test_this = [{"search": "person"}, { search: "another person"}];
var json = JSON.stringify(test_this);
urlSearchParams.append("myobj", json);

return this.http.post(this.post_url, urlSearchParams, options) //options being your own RequestOptions
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Something like this might work `urlSearchParams = Object.assign(urlSearchParams, {search: "person"});`

EDIT: Alternate solution using vanilla javascript.  Also, I thought URLSearchParams was just a normal js object, but in fact you have to use `get`, `set` and `append` to access properties.

```js
var params = new URLSearchParams("a=apple&b=balloon");
var parametersToAdd = {c: "car", d: "duck"};
for(key in parametersToAdd)
  params.append(key, parametersToAdd[key]);

console.log(params.get('c'));
console.log(params.get('d'));
```

EDIT bis:
`.append()` supports to re-use the same key/parameter name, while `.set()` would have overwritten a previous value.

Comment: I tried this `let search = Object.assign(urlSearchParams, {number: '5'});` but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: i tried code like that in the chrome console and it worked.  what browser are you working with? `let` is a newer keyword so maybe try it with just var.  Also, the Object.assign method is not available in IE as per the documentation

Comment: Just a note of caution: If you want to retain existing parameters with the same name, `append` should be used instead of `set`. [URLSearchParams on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Answer (score 4):

May be using below code you can pass entire json object in URL Search param

```
var json = JSON.stringify(myObj);

this.http.get('url'+'?myobj='+encodeURIComponent(json))
```

Comment: I'm actually using this.http.post so it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: you can also use post same way this.http.post('url'+'?myobj='+encodeURIComponent(json))

Comment: If I could mark two answers I would mark yours too, but the other answer is better suited to the question :(

Answer (score 3):

There's no API for that. You just need to enumerate over the properties and append them manually, for example using the following function:

```
function appendParams(params: URLSearchParams, obj: any) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      params.append(key, obj[key])
    }
  }
}

appendParams(urlSearchParams, { search: 'person' });
```

Comment: is it possible to send an array with that?

Answer (score 3):

Want to share my answer for `Angular2` with the option of sending an `Array`
This is how I use this `get` function:

```
this.get('/api/database', {
   'age': [1,2,3,4]
})
```

And the service is something like:

```
get(url, _params = {}) {
    let params = this._processParams(_params);

    return this.http.get(url, params).toPromise();
}

_processParams(obj: any) {
        /* Convert this
            { age: [1,2,3] }
           To:
              param.append('age', 1);
              param.append('age', 2);
              param.append('age', 3);
        */        
        let params = new URLSearchParams();

        for (let key in obj) {
            for (let index in obj[key] ) {                
                params.append(key, obj[key][index]);
            }
        }

        return {
            search: params
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Super simple **answer/example:**

```js
// Create:
const params = new URLSearchParams({
  a: 1,
  b: 2
})
// OR
// const params = new URLSearchParams("a=1&b=2")

// Append
params.append('c', 'woohoo') // Note: if c param already exists in params, this will replace it (won't be adding new param if already exists, hence no duplications)

console.log(params.toString())
// Prints: 'a=1&b=2&c=woohoo'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach. We have a simple requirement where the object is only a key value pair where the value might be a string or an array. We haven't found a use case for nested objects.

So let's say we want to convert this object into a query string or vice versa:

```js
const input = {
  ini: 'ini',
  itu: 'itu',
  ayo: ['desc', 'asc'],
}
```

Then we have two functions to parse & stringify:

```js
function stringify(input) {
  const params = new URLSearchParams();

  for (const key in input) {
    if (Array.isArray(input[key])) {
      input[key].forEach(val => {
        params.append(key + '[]', val)
      })
    } else {
      params.append(key, input[key]);
    }
  }

  return '?' + params.toString();
}
```

```js
function parse(input) {
  const payload = {};
  const params = new URLSearchParams(input);

  for(let [key, val] of params.entries()) {
    if (key.endsWith('[]')) {
      key = key.replace(/\[\]$/, '');
      if (payload[key]) {
        payload[key].push(val);
      } else {
        payload[key] = [val]
      }
    } else {
      payload[key] = val;
    }
  }

  return payload;
}
```

So the result should be `"?ini=ini&itu=itu&ayo%5B%5D=desc&ayo%5B%5D=asc"`. This is similar to the array format that is found in [this example](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string#arrayformat-1).

Please note that this might not be battle tested, but for us we don't really have complicated object structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
const url = new URL('/', location.origin);
console.log(url.href); // https://stackoverflow.com/
Object.entries({this:4,that:1}).forEach((item)=>{ 
// note .set replaces while .append will duplicate params
    url.searchParams.append(...item);
});
console.log(url.href); // https://stackoverflow.com/?this=4&that=1
```